# 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000034

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone

When my character (flappy bird) contacts obstacles, it shall turns to a gameover scene. The problem is yes it shows up a gameover scene but same time appears the

> 0x0FBE9B95 (libcocos2d_2015.dll) 中 (於 FlappyBird.exe) 擲回例外狀況: 0xC0000005: 讀取位置 0x00000034 時發生存取違規。

To translate:

> 0x0FBE9B95 in (libcocos2d_2015.dll) (under FlappyBird.exe) throws an exception 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000034.

However, when I hide out all the background stuff as well as `_scheduleUpdate()_`, the exception disappears! (Also nothing comes up to the scene...but know that the physics is still here, my flappy bird can fall to ground and turn to gameover scene)
Here is my program:

(GameScene.cpp)

```
#include "GameScene.h"
#include "GameOverScene.h"
#include "cocostudio/CocoStudio.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"
#include "Defination.h"

USING_NS_CC;

using namespace cocostudio::timeline;

Scene* GameScene::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
    scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = GameScene::create();
    layer->setPhysicsWorld(scene->getPhysicsWorld());

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool GameScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    auto origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    /*Set screen boundary so that characters will not move outside screen*/
    auto edgeBody = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(visibleSize, 
    PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT, 3);
    edgeBody->setCollisionBitmask(OBSTACLE_COLLISION_BITMASK);
    edgeBody->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    auto edgeNode = Node::create();

    edgeNode->setPhysicsBody(edgeBody);
    edgeNode->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, 
    visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));

    this->addChild(edgeNode);

    /*BG*/
    bgLayer = Layer::create();

    bgTotalWidth = 0;
    auto sprite = Sprite::create("bg1.png");
    float bgScale = visibleSize.height / sprite->getContentSize().height;
    float bgWidth = sprite->getContentSize().width * bgScale;
    sprite->release();
    allSpriteScale = bgScale;

    while (bgTotalWidth < visibleSize.width + bgWidth) {
        auto bgSprite = Sprite::create("bg1.png");
        bgSprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
        bgSprite->setPosition(Point(origin.x + bgTotalWidth, origin.y));
        bgSprite->setScale(bgScale);

        auto scrollAction = RepeatForever::create(MoveBy::create(1, Vec2(-
        BACKGROUND_MOVE_SPEED, 0)));
        bgSprite->runAction(scrollAction);

        bgLayer->addChild(bgSprite);

        bgTotalWidth += bgWidth;
    }

    this->addChild(bgLayer, 0);

    /*Pipe*/
    pipe = Pipe::Pipe(allSpriteScale);
    pipeLayer = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(pipeLayer, 1);

    /*Flappy Bird*/
    playerLayer = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(playerLayer, 2);
    bird = &FlappyBird::FlappyBird(allSpriteScale, playerLayer);

    /*Scheduler*/
    scheduleUpdate(); //Enable update
    schedule(schedule_selector(GameScene::spawnPipe), PIPE_SPAWN_INTERVAL);

    auto collisionListener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
    collisionListener->onContactBegin = 
    CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onContactBegin, this);
    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()-
    >addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(collisionListener, this);

    return true;
}

void GameScene::update(float delta) {
    /*BG Update*/
    for each (Sprite* sp in bgLayer->getChildren())
    {
        if (sp->getPositionX() <= -(sp->getContentSize().width * sp-
    >getScaleX())) {
            sp->setPosition(Point(bgTotalWidth + sp->getPositionX(), 0));
            break;
        }
      }
    }

  void GameScene::spawnPipe(float delta) {
    pipe.Spawn(pipeLayer);
 }

bool GameScene::onContactBegin(PhysicsContact &contact)
{
    PhysicsBody* a = contact.getShapeA()->getBody();
    PhysicsBody* b = contact.getShapeB()->getBody();

    if ( (a->getCollisionBitmask() == FLAPPYBIRD_COLLISION_BITMASK && b-
  >getCollisionBitmask() == OBSTACLE_COLLISION_BITMASK) ||
        (b->getCollisionBitmask() == FLAPPYBIRD_COLLISION_BITMASK && a-
  >getCollisionBitmask() == OBSTACLE_COLLISION_BITMASK)
        ) 
    {


        auto gameoverScene = GameOverScene::createScene();
        Director::getInstance()-
   >replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(SCENE_TRANSITION_DURATION, 
   gameoverScene));
    }

    return true;
   }
```

The crush line indicated by Visual Studio is in main.cpp:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // create the application instance
    AppDelegate app;
    return Application::getInstance()->run(); // Crush here
}
```

One more interesting thing, I could hardly change my code! In `_init()_`, if I just hide out the 2 lines defining my background sprites actions (logically that would not affect others), the exception will come up in my GameScene!

It is very very weird......hope someone can help me out. :(

Comment: AFAIK, that means you're accessing memory you don't own. This is way too much code to expect us to go through for you though. You really need to narrow the problem down to a [MCVE].

Comment: From the error message this is Windows. Really, the best thing for you to do is step through your program with the Visual Studio debugger and narrow down where you are attempting to write to memory you don't own.

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate, thanks for your reply. I understand that but there's too much code for me to post here...and the exception windows actually is written in Chinese so I can't post it directly...I am thinking other ways clarifying my case actually. Appreciate if u can understand.

Comment: The whole exception message is:
"0x0FBE9B95 (libcocos2d_2015.dll) 中 (於 FlappyBird.exe) 擲回例外狀況: 0xC0000005: 讀取位置 0x00000034 時發生存取違規。"
I try to translate that: 0x0FBE9B95 in (libcocos2d_2015.dll) (under FlappyBird.exe) throws an exception: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000034

Comment: Note how close 0x00000034 is to zero. Somewhere out there, beneath the pale moonlight, you likely have a null pointer to a structure. Letting whatever debugger came with your development environment run until it hits the error and breaks is probably the easiest thing to do to find the crash site. Not that the crash site is necessarily where the actual bug is, but you at least know what got run over and can work back from there.

Comment: I run it line by line, Visual Studio tells there is no libcocos2d.pdb to define symbols in libcocos2d_2015.dll. Is that relevant?

Comment: added the crush line marked by Visual Studio when exception occurs

Comment: With the situation that if I comment out the 2 lines adding scrollAction, the exception will also occur. Is that Visual Studio already pre-occupied some memory location for it so I have to use it, meanwhile other classes or say variables don't know the location is occupied so still try to use the memory location. Just a thought...not an expert in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `sprite->release()`, this line causes the exception. Sprite class is already an auto-release object and registered in the auto-release pool once it is spawned.

So, when calling `replaceScene()` , all objects shall not be called will be released. However, it cannot reference the sprite in auto-release pool because it was already released by the line `sprite->release()` and caused error.